# why ol.proj.transform function is not working in openlayers3

Tags: openlayers

I have a problem in openLayers3

It has a function name is 'ol.proj.transform'

I want to change to 'EPSG:4326' coordinates from 'EPSG:5186' coordinates

```
var lonlat1 = ol.proj.transform([111111.1111,222222.2222222],'EPSG:5186','EPSG:4326');

console.log(lonlat1);
```

lonlat1 value is [111111.1111,222222.2222222]

ol.proj.transform not working

why function is not working ??

How to use ol.proj.transform function

help me please...

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with EPSG:5186 format; however, here is a similar example that appears to be working (demonstrating a case where `ol.proj.transform()` function works as expected):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="ol/v3.18.2/build/ol.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  ol.proj.transform([-85.49675,38.60643333], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  <script>
   var lonlat1 = ol.proj.transform([-85.49675,38.60643333], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
   console.log(lonlat1);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Giving the following result in console:

```
Array [ -9517454.674479812, 4665452.296008711 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that ol.proj doesn't include EPSG:5186 by default. Luckily, you can add custom projections using the [Proj4 library](http://proj4js.org/).

Download the proj4.js script and include it on your map page.

Also include the definition of EPSG:5186 from [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/5186) :

```
<script src="https://epsg.io/5186.js"></script>
```

Now before you do your transformation, define the projection in a variable:

```
var koreanProj = ol.proj.get('EPSG:5186');
```

And finally, use that variable in your transformation:

```
var lonlat1 = ol.proj.transform([111111.1111,222222.2222222], koreanProj, 'EPSG:4326');
```

Answer (score 1):

you also need

`ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);`

after the epsg script.